# How to make a open/close door with an action range?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting

I want to make a door which opens and closes by pressing a button ( "O" for open and "C" for close). Tried with this:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
public class DoorScript : MonoBehaviour {

public float speed;
public float angle;
public Vector3 direction;
    // use this for initializaton
    void start() {
        angle = transform.eulerAngles.y;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {
        if (Mathf.Round(transform.eulerAngles.y) != angle) {
            //rotate our door
            transform.Rotate(direction * speed);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.O)) {
            angle = 90;
            direction = Vector3.up;
        } 

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C)) {
            angle = 0;
            direction = -Vector3.up;
     }
   }
}
```

But it did not works how I want. I mean: You can be far away, if you press "O" the door will open anyway. How can I implement an action range? I mean, you will need to be a little bit closer to the door interact with it?
I also need to say that in the game will me aprox. 40 doors. I need for each other a custom script?

The code is in C#. I have a little bit of coding experience, but i can´t solve this.

Thanks

Comment: `Vector3.Distance(transform, player.transform)`? Of course, that requires that every door know about the player, which should never be the case (what happens when you have more than one player? What about other agents that want to open doors?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to use Colliders, RigidBodies and OnTrigger calls.  Here is a manual page that outlines the usage.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html

For your implementation, the door would have the Example script (call it something other than "Example") and the player would be the sphere (although you would create the player outside of this script).  When the player is near a door, the door will know it by keeping track of the presence of the player through the OnTrigger calls.  Then, when the key is pressed, the door will react if the user is nearby.  Every door would have a script like this.